# Why would Firebase signInAnonymously() stop working?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

The platform is ReactJS. All calls are from localhost. The code is very standard and has been working up until this post.

Edit: I believe this started happening right after a `firebase deploy`

```
function loginAnon() {
    console.log("anon login called")
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function (error) {
      console.log("anon signin error", error)
    });
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  console.log('user', user)
  // more code to create a user in firestore etc
}
```

No error is seen from the signIn call. The auth state change is called. Console says:

```
anon login called        App.js:33
user null                App.js:40
```

There was no reason to do so but to be doubly sure I have raised the signup quota to 1000 per hour (from 100). Anonymous login has always been enabled.

Comment: That sounds unexpected indeed, although it depends a bit on the timing of the logs. Can you set up a reproduction on a site like jsbin or similar, so that I can have a look?

Comment: frank, i will do that shortly. however i just figured that this started happening after a [firebase deploy]. is it possible some configuration file wrt auth was overwritten in the process and preventing this?

Answer (score 0):

This had nothing to do with Firebase or ReactJS but a simple inadvertent form submit that was calling `loginAnon()` and reloading the page thus wiping out the `onAuthChanged` handler. Code:

```
  <form>
    <button onClick={loginAnon}>Login</button>
  </form>
```

Removing the form tag fixes the problem. If mod suggests I can update the question with this info or delete this question entirely.